# Calling different Views in one Controller Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a WebApp that does repeated calculations in one Controller Action. I want the page to update, every time a part of the result has been calculated. 
So for example at the start of the calculation the browser loads a view that says "Calculations are running", then after the first calculation it says "A has been calculated" and when it's done it loads a View that says "Completed".

SignalR seems like overkill for this, is there any way in Asp.Net?

Comment: How is SignalR an overkill?

Comment: without signalR you'd have to call multiple ajax calls for each calculation and chain them.

Comment: I'm not going to use it for anything else on that site, even just installing the SignalR packages seems a bit much for what little I am trying to achieve: All I want is for the user to have some kind of feedback instead of a site that takes 5 minutes to load.

Comment: Basically I want Console.WriteLine() for a MVC Web-App :p

Comment: @Vaethin, and it basically does not exist, because of the nature of http protocol. There are techniques to emulate that, and SignalR wraps them up nicely, and there is no point reinventing them on your own instead

Comment: @Vaethin is this a polling process that is checking the status of "A"?

Comment: I agree with @Andrei, SignalR is definitely not overkill.  The only other simple way to achieve that sort of functionality would be to constantly make ajax request until your result is updated.  I've used SignalR exclusively for purposes like this within an app.  There is no added bloat, and it's pretty simple to inject.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using multiple JQuery AJAX Posts. AJAX Posts by default will run asynchronously, therefore you could run all of your Posts at the same time, perhaps when the form loads or on button click. As they complete you can change the text that is displayed on the screen to reflect the result from the last request that completed.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: {},
    success: function (data) {
        $("#calculationStatus").html(data);
    }
});
```

You can also use a HTML progress bar along with any message related to the completed calculation.